# Indexing data.frame from vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

I have a very simple indexing question.  If I have two variables A and B

```
A = c(1,2,1,1) 
B = data.frame( x = c(1,2), y=c( 'up', 'down') )
```

I need to have a output of A that results like

> [1] "up" "down" "up" "up"

My code is this

```
 B[ which(A %in% B$x), ]$y
```

But I get

> [1] "up"   "down" NA     NA

Which is the shortest way to fix my code?

Comment: `B[A, "y"]` or `B$y[A]`

Comment: `B[match(A, B$x), "y"]`

Comment: Thank you! @GregorThomas

Comment: @Roland, this is also other solution!
Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure why, but @Roland option is the one that worked with my complete dataset.

Comment: That's because my approach doesn't make such strong assumptions regarding `B$x` as the one by @GregorThomas.

Comment: Yeah - I'm using `A` as row numbers. If that's not the case for any reason - basically if `B$x` isn't `1:n`, then Roland's `match` solution is what you want. Re-reading your question, I can see `x` coming up in your attempt, but in my first read I just thought it was row numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to think about this:

You want the `A`-indexed elements of the `y` column of `B` - so extract the `y` column with `$` and apply the index `A` with `[`.

```
B$y[A]
```

Or, you want the `A`-indexed rows of `B`, and you only care about the `y` column, use the standard data frame indexing of `data[rows, columns]`:

```
B[A, "y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named vectors:

```
unname(c("1" = "up", "2" = "down")[A])
[1] "up"   "down" "up"   "up"
```

Comment: This would be a much stronger answer if you showed OP how to construct the named vector from their inputs - presumably this is a minimal illustrative example and they may have many more `A` and `y` values.